# How do I see what questions have been asked to my Microsoft Azure Language Understanding Web app bot using a LUIS app as a Knowledge base?

Tags: azure, bots

I’ve developed a Language Understanding web app bot in azure. It uses a LUIS app as knowledge base. I want to see what questions were asked to my bot by the users. I referred to [How to track what users ask on chatbot ( Microsoft Azure Bot Service )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404534/how-to-track-what-users-ask-on-chatbot-microsoft-azure-bot-service) which answers a similar question. But my bot here uses Luis as a knowledge base rather than QnAMaker one. Can someone help me to modify the script?

I've read that we can see what users asked our chatbot by doing the following:
 Log in to your Azure Bot account. After that navigate to the Dashboard and look at botname-ai file. Click that and find Analyze option. Then run this command:

```
  requests
| where url endswith "generateAnswer"
| project timestamp, id, name, resultCode, duration
| parse name with *"/knowledgebases/"KbId"/generateAnswer"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| extend question = tostring(customDimensions['Question'])
| extend answer = tostring(customDimensions['Answer'])
| project KbId, timestamp, resultCode, duration, question, answer
```

But in my case it shows 0 records found. My best guess is, this is because, I'm not using a QnA Maker Knowledge Base. Rather I'm using a LUIS app. I've tried editing the script, but it would always either give a syntax error or show "0 records found". But questions were asked to the bot during that time.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but it still comes up.  For SDK v4 I would query the customEvents table.  The following should get you started:

```
customEvents
| where name endswith "LuisResult"
| extend cd=parse_json(customDimensions)
| extend Text=coalesce(cd.text, cd.Text, cd.OriginalQuestion, cd.question)
| project timestamp, name, Text, cd.intent, cd.intentScore
```